# How to sum the elements of 2 lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [10,11,12,13,14]
```

And I want to sum, each the elements of the lists, like list1[0]+list2[0], list1[1]+list2[1]....And have a new list:

```
newlist = [11,13,15,17,19]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `zip`/`map`:

```
result = list(map(sum,zip(list1,list2)))
```

Alternative, via `list_comprehension`:

```
result = [i+j for i,j in zip(list1,list2)]
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
[11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

Comment: Not your downvote (Answer is fine). But Usually people downvote when the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Use the vectorised operations from numpy

```
import numpy as np
newlist = list(np.array(list1) + np.array(list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
zipped_lists = zip(list1, list2) 
sum = [x + y for (x, y) in zipped_lists]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple for loop

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [10,11,12,13,14]
result = [list1[i]+list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
print(result)
```